# pom.xmlの1行目でエラー cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'

Tags: java, xml

Javaプロジェクトでpom.xmlのエラーがどうしても解消できません。
pom.xmlの1行目を記載します。

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

エラー内容：

```
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'.
```

見当もつかず、かなり説明不足かと思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: なるべく関連するコードは省略せずに質問に含めた方が回答のヒントになるかと思います。質問は後からでも編集できるので、必要に応じて追記してください。

Comment: その行自体に問題は無さそうに見えます。 プロジェクトエクスプローラ上で `pom.xml` を右クリック > "Validate" を実行すると解消したりしないでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick
ありがとうございます。編集してわかりやすくします。

Comment: @DEWA Kazuyuki
Eclipseでやっていますが、「検証」してもエラー消えませんでした。
ただ、エラーが突然消えたりまた現れるのでそういうエラーなのかもしれません。もう少し調べてみます。回答ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

Eclipseのバージョンを変更したらなぜか解決しました。
自己解決しましたので、クローズします。